# Which NLP is better for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, nlp, raspberry-pi, arm, stanford-nlp

I'm looking for a NLP library for Raspberry Pi Model B+. I tried to install *spaCy* but it seems some packages like *blis* don't support 32 bit versions. I tried to build from source also. Finally I gave up. 
Now I'm looking for a spaCy alternative which can be installed in ARM devices like Pi. Something should be fast. Will Stanford coreNLP work on Raspberry Pi?. I read that it's heavy and slow.

Answer (score 0):

Stanford coreNLP runs in a Java Virtual Machine. So long as you are able to install a JRE on your device you should be able to run coreNLP. More information on how to install Java on a Raspberry Pi can be found [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4683/how-to-install-the-java-jdk-on-raspberry-pi).

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B with 4GB of RAM that I got set up to run a project that used coreNLP, but it didn't end up working because it didn't have enough RAM to load the neural dependency parser. Depending on what you are doing with coreNLP memory requirements will be a problem when running on a Raspberry Pi but the platform itself shouldn't stop you from getting it set up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried coreNLP and yeah it's slow. Mine is Pi3 with 1 GB RAM. Finally I ended up with NLTK and it seems fine for my application which is using basic things like `pos_tag` and `sentence tokenization`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your limitations, but wouldn't it make more sense to upgrade to a RPi 5 with 8GB of RAM? It does offer 64 bit, and the RPi 5 has a PCIe that could allow the addition of more memory.